# Log4j2 JDBC Appender PoolingDriver configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j2

I'm trying to configure Log4j2 using JDBC Appender with the following `log4j2.xml` file for my Spring Boot application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <JDBC name="DB" tableName="log">
            <PoolingDriver connectionString="url" userName="username" password="password"/>
            <Column name="COD_LOG_ID" literal="log0.nextval"/>
            <Column name="TIM_TIMESTAM" isEventTimestamp="true"/>
            <Column name="DES_LOGGER" pattern="%c"/>
            <Column name="COD_JLEVEL" pattern="%level"/>
            <Column name="DES_LMESSAGE" pattern="%m%n%ex{full}" isClob="true"/>
        </JDBC>

        <Async name="Async">
            <AppenderRef ref="DB"/>
        </Async>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="Async"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

But trying to run the application produces the following error:

```
2023-06-07 12:36:23,622 main ERROR No ConnectionSource provided: connectionSource
2023-06-07 12:36:23,628 main ERROR Could not create plugin of type class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.JdbcAppender for element JDBC org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationException: Arguments given for element JDBC are invalid: field 'connectionSource' has invalid value 'null'
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.injectFields(PluginBuilder.java:210)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:121)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:1120)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1045)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1037)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:651)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:247)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:293)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:626)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:699)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:716)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:270)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog.<clinit>(LogAdapter.java:155)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:122)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:89)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactoryService.getInstance(LogFactoryService.java:46)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactoryService.getInstance(LogFactoryService.java:41)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:655)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<clinit>(SpringApplication.java:196)
    at com.bbva.eysea.ganbaru.Application.main(Application.java:28)
```

Replacing `PoolingDriver` with `DriverManager` works, but according to [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#jdbcappender) I should use a pooling connection, which is theoretically provided by `PoolingDriver`. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PoolingDriver` plugin is not distributed in `log4j-core`.

If you are using Maven, you need to add:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-jdbc-dbcp2</artifactId>
    <version>2.20.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

to your dependencies.

Comment: It'd be really interesting to know how did you get to know this. I could not find this information anywhere...

Comment: @thmasker: that is an excellent question. I usually look at the code, because as we are painfully aware, the documentation is awful. We are working on improving it, but in the meantime you can [report a documentation issue](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/issues), possibly with together with a PR.